# No self_obj (RuntimeError) cucumber capybara whenever I use double quotes on my feature file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

Whenever I use double quotes in cucumber feature file and accordingly I prepare RegularEexpression for step definition I always land to this error.
Please need help to resolve this.
In my features project I have the following documentations:

Feature :Amazon Sign In page

Scenario: Search for a term
    Given I am on on Amazon Sign in Page
    When I enter email Id on Login Page
    And I click on Continue button
    And I enter Password on Login Page
    And I click on Login button
    Then Page should have content "Hello, abc"

my step definitions steps

Then(/^Page should have content "(.*?)"$/) do |text|
  page.should have_content text
end

Error:-
 Then Page should have content "Hello, abc" # features/step_definitions/
_page.rb:72
   No self_obj (RuntimeError)
   features/Home_Page.Feature:17:in `Then Page should have content "Hello, abc"

```
my gem list
actionmailer (5.1.4)
actionpack (5.1.4)
actionview (5.1.4)
activejob (5.1.4)
activemodel (5.1.4)
activerecord (5.1.4)
activesupport (5.1.4)
addressable (2.5.2)
appium_lib (9.7.5, 9.7.3)
arel (8.0.0)
awesome_print (1.8.0)
backports (3.10.3)
bigdecimal (1.2.8)
builder (3.2.3)
capybara (2.16.1, 2.15.4)
childprocess (0.8.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
crass (1.0.3)
cucumber (3.0.2, 3.0.1)
cucumber-core (3.0.0)
cucumber-expressions (5.0.3, 4.0.4)
cucumber-tag_expressions (1.0.1)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.3)
erubi (1.7.0)
ffi (1.9.18 x64-mingw32)
gherkin (5.0.0, 4.1.3)
globalid (0.4.1)
i18n (0.9.1)
io-console (0.4.5)
json (1.8.3)
loofah (2.1.1)
mail (2.7.0)
mini_mime (1.0.0, 0.1.4)
mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
minitest (5.10.3, 5.8.5)
multi_json (1.12.2)
multi_test (0.1.2)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.8.1 x64-mingw32)
power_assert (1.1.1, 0.2.6)
psych (2.1.0)
public_suffix (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
rack (2.0.3)
rack-test (0.8.2, 0.7.0)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
rake (12.3.0, 10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.1)
rspec (3.7.0)
rspec-core (3.7.0)
rspec-expectations (3.7.0)
rspec-mocks (3.7.0)
rspec-support (3.7.0)
rubyzip (1.2.1)
selenium-webdriver (3.6.0)
test-unit (3.1.5)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tomlrb (1.2.5)
tzinfo (1.2.4)
xpath (2.1.0)
```

Please help me here.

Comment: Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message

> No self_obj (RuntimeError)

I think this is an incorrect cucumber installation, not reporting underlying errors properly.
I see the error when I run `cucumber`, but when I run `bundle exec cucumber` then I see the underlying error reported correctly.

For completeness, my `cucumber` installation was:

- install homebrew
- install rbenv
- rbenv init and edit ~./bash_profile
- rbenv install 2.3.6
- rbenv global 2.3.6
- gem install bundler
- set up a Gemfile with cucumber and dependencies
- bundle install
  and then I forgot to do bundle exec, and instead did gem install cucumber, which seems to have got me in the problem state

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to cucumber-expressions 5.0.13